# Increase font-size

Tags: javascript, html, loops, fonts

I'm trying to make a program where you type in a text, then you type in how many times you want to see the text. Then the font-size would increase 10% per line. Here's my code so far:

```
function addElement()
{
var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
var ggr = document.getElementById("ggr").value*1;
var output= "";
for(var i=0; i < ggr; i++)
{
    output += "<div " + "style=\"font-size: 10%"+i+"\" " + " >" + text  + "</div>" + "<br />";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
}

<h2>Write your text here</h2>
<input type="text" id="text" value="" /> </br>
<h2>How many times do you want to see it?</h2>
<input type="text" id="ggr" value="" /> </br>
<input type="button" value="Resultat" onClick="addElement();"/></br>
<div id="result"/>
```

How can increase the fontsize by 10% at every line?

Comment: well how about `10*i+"%"` ... now it goes 10%, 20%, 30%...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code writes `10%0`, `10%1`, `10%2`, ...etc.

Change this line :

```
    output += "<div " + "style=\"font-size: "+((i+1)*10)+"%\" " + " >" + text  + "</div>" + "<br />";
```

This will start at 10%, and grows by 10% each line (`10%`, `20%`, `30%`, ...).

Answer (score 1):

The + operator add [i] variable as string , you need it as number
,so the best option to keep the operations out of string.

```
var font_start_size= 100;// Value of first size
    for(var i=0; i < ggr; i++)
    {
        var size = (10 * i) + font_start_size; 
        output += "<div style='font-size: "+size+"%'>" + text  + "</div>" + "<br />";
    }
```

code after **fix**:

```js
function addElement()
{
var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
var ggr = document.getElementById("ggr").value*1;
var output= "";
for(var i=0; i < ggr; i++)
{
 var font_start_size= 100;// Value of first size
 var size = (10 * i) + font_start_size; 
    output += "<div style='font-size: "+size+"%'>" + text  + "</div>" + "<br />";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;
}
```

```html
<h2>Write your text here</h2>
<input type="text" id="text" value="" /> </br>
<h2>How many times do you want to see it?</h2>
<input type="number" id="ggr" value="" /> </br>
<input type="button" value="Resultat" onClick="addElement();"/></br>
<div id="result"/>
```